# After updating to macOS 10.13.5 it asked for iCloud account and password

Tags: macos, mac

I Update To Mac Os 10.13.5 From High Sierra After Updating MacBook it again ask for icloud password and id is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s normal behaviour for a MacOS upgrade.

Comment: It Also Automatically Enable Guest Account is it also normal ?